# How do I set a variable inside of \rlap

Tags: macros, conditionals

Two questions please about this code example:

1) Why does `\rlap` prevent me from setting a variable?
2) How do I set a variable from within an `\rlap` that is visible outside of `\rlap`?

I'm using MikTex 2.8.  Thanks for any clue!

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmycheck
\begin{document}
\rlap{\mychecktrue}
% \mychecktrue
\ifmycheck
Check True!
\else
Check False!  % always takes this path!
\fi
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Changes within a group stay inside that group, and `\rlap` puts its argument inside an `\hbox`, therefore within its own group.  So if you did:

   ```
   \rlap{\mychecktrue % group is still open!
   % \mychecktrue
   \ifmycheck
   Check True!
   \else
   Check False!  
   \fi}
   ```

   You will get

   > Check True!

   So you see that you did set the variable inside `\rlap`.
2. You want the changes to persist outside the group.  So use the prefix `\global`:

   ```
   \rlap{\global\mychecktrue}
   % \mychecktrue
   \ifmycheck
   Check True!
   \else
   Check False!  
   \fi
   ```

   That will result again in "Check True!"

Comment: What you say is correct except that it implies that setting a conditional inside the argument of *any* macro is local; this is not the case.  (Try `\def\mymac#1{#1}`, for example.)  The braces around a macro argument do not form a group; in the case of `\rlap`, it is because the argument is placed inside an `\hbox`, and the contents of an `\hbox` (or `\vbox`, etc.) *do* form a group.

Comment: @Ryan:  You are correct, good sir.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Matthew's answer, a solution other than setting the variable globally is to use aftergroup to delay the assignment until after the group (produced by `\hbox`) is finished. Your example becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmycheck
\begin{document}
\rlap{\aftergroup\mychecktrue}
\ifmycheck
Check True!
\else
Check False!  
\fi
\end{document}
```

and now typesets `Check True!`.